# div following mousepointer also over other div

Tags: z-index

I prepared a website with Wordpress and DIVI (https://roel.famnabuurs.nl). There is one issue left before I can finish this website, so hope someone can help me.
If you visit the website you see the mousepointer is replaced by a  containing some text. When you move the pointer to the right side, if you shift to the  right next to it, the text remains visible. I arranged that via the z-index on the column-div. That's also the way it should work.
The issue is more downwards, were the image shows 'NOW'. If I move my mouse to the right side, the textblock disappears (moves behind the column to the right). And that's not okay. It should behave the same way as above.
I already tried several settings covering z-index, on the column, module and image level, but nothing helps. I already spend days to find out, but not successful.

Could someone please have a look?

Answer (score 0):

I already solved the issue; it was caused by a overflow: hidden setting on a div. I changed this setting to 'visible', and now it shifts over the other div